# What does adding HD to a construct affect?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters

I am building a Homunculus, and I want to add 3 HD to it so it has 5 HD. However, I'm not clear on what happens as a result of these HD being added. I've read [the monster advancement page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/monster-advancement), but all I'm sure about is that the 3 HD add skill points and 2 feats.

Can anyone clarify what exactly happens depending on the HD added?

A list of what happens with each added HD would be very helpful.

Comment: According to the table here: http://paizo.com/PRD/monsters/monsterCreation.html constructs with 5HD are CR4, a change of +3 CR. Using this information, the tables you linked should be much easier to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what's the final form of an homunculus and why.

Let's reference [the creature's stats, as per the pathfinder srd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/constructs/homunculus)

As you can see, the *hp* line tells us it's a "(2d10)" HD monster.
We're going to add 3 more HD, making it a 5d10 HD monster. Whether you should take the mean value of the dice or roll them depends on your DM.

Now, several other things in the statblock depend on the creature's HD.
I will start from the things that are gonna influence others, instead of top-down.

First of all, every 4th level a character gains an ability score increase. Since the homunculus goes from 2HD to 5HD, he gains one. Decide where this will go.
You will probably notice he gained it based on his total HD, not on the HD he gained over its base form. This will be true for every change we're gonna make.
If you can raise any of its abilities to an even value, this will reflect on otheer values as well. Let's say it's dexterity. Armor class goes up by one, as does the reflex save.

Second, you need to re-calculate the Base Attack Bonus and the Saves, using [the Construct progression table](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Construct).
A construct has all bad saves (0 0 1 1 1 progression) so it goes from a +0 to a +1 base saving throw bonus.
A construct also has a good BAB (1 1 1 1 1 progression) so it goes from a +2 to a +5 BAB.

Third, every odd level you gain a feat. So you gain one at 3 and one at 5.

Fourth, as per the construct table you gain 2+Int skill points per level (since the homunculus has a Int score) and your maximum ranks increase accordingly to your new HD.

When calculating AC and attack lines remember to factor in the +2 bonuses for size and the (eventually) new Str or Dex score

Answer (score 0):

A construct, when it gains a Hit Die, gets:

> A D10(5.5HP), +1BAB, Saving Throw progression of Poor(Ie: Fighter's Will Save), Skill Points = 2+int(min 1) assuming a
>   non-mindless construct, Feats as per normal character progression(1 at
>   first, 1 at 3rd, ect.)

All creatures follow the creature type rule unless specified elsewhere(such as in the specific monster description).